# Submit form only if value of input change

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have a form with some input fields and I am using some firebase methods to update those fields. But everytime when clicking the submit button the entire form is submitting. How can I check if any if the fields value changed. For an example if display name remains same then the updateProfile method will not run on submit. Please find the code below. onUpdateProfile is the form submit method.

```js
{
  methods: {
    onUpdateProfile() {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user) {
          //Getting Current User

          //Updating User name on submit
          let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
          user
            .updateProfile({
              displayName: this.profile.name
            })
            .then(() => {
              this.formSuccess = "Name changed successfully.";
              setTimeout(() => {
                $(".form-success").fadeOut("slow");
              }, 2500);
            })
            .catch(error => {});

          //Updating User other details on submit
          const db = firebase.firestore().collection("profiles");
          db.get()
            .then(doc => {
              if (doc.exists) {
                //If user data exists it will update
                db.doc(user.uid)
                  .update({
                    phonenumber: this.profile.phonenumber,
                    fulladdress: this.profile.fullAddress,
                    zipcode: this.profile.zipcode
                  })
                  .then(() => {
                    this.formSuccess = "Profile Updated successfully.";
                    setTimeout(() => {
                      $(".form-success").fadeOut("slow");
                    }, 2500);
                  })
                  .catch(error => {});
              } else {
                //If user data not exists it will create new collection and add the new user records
                db.doc(user.uid)
                  .set({
                    phonenumber: this.profile.phonenumber,
                    fulladdress: this.profile.fullAddress,
                    zipcode: this.profile.zipcode
                  })
                  .then(() => {
                    this.formSuccess = "Profile Updated successfully.";
                    setTimeout(() => {
                      $(".form-success").fadeOut("slow");
                    }, 2500);
                  })
                  .catch(error => {});
              }
            })
            .catch(error => {});
        } else {}
      });
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      profile: {
        name: "",
        email: "",
        phonenumber: "",
        fullAddress: "",
        zipcode: "",
      },
      formSuccess: null
    };
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only update the user document if there are any changes, you'll need to compare the values inside the document with the values from the form. Something like this:

```
//Updating User other details on submit
const db = firebase.firestore().collection("profiles");
db.doc(user.uid).get()
  .then(doc => {
    if (doc.exists) {
      var updates = {};
      if (doc.data().phonenumber != this.profile.phonenumber) updates["phonenumer"] = this.profile.phonenumber;
      if (doc.data().fulladdress != this.profile.fullAddress) updates["fulladdress"] = this.profile.fullAddress;
      if (doc.data().zipcode != this.profile.zipcode) updates["zipcode"] = this.profile.zipcode;

      if (Object.keys(updates).length > 0) {
        db.doc(user.uid).update(updates)
      }
```

The changes I made here:

1. Your code loaded all user profiles, while the above only load the profile of the current user.
2. Build an `updates` object with only the values that have changed.
3. Only update the database if there are any changes.

Comment: and for else part like db.doc.set() will remain same?

Comment: Since there is no existing data in the `else` part, you won't have to do the comparisons there.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen is it better to evaluate the data using the firestore triggers. Like onUpdate? then we can do our logic inside that codeblock?

Comment: I think onUpdate trigger is a better approach since it will show you the difference in the data in the object.

Comment: How can i add a success message here. Everytime if any these fields get updated user should get a success message. I was trying but I can see the message only first time if i update any of the fields after that if I update any field can not see that message